# Do reaction times differ for different response types?

Tags: statistical-significance, reaction-time

I have two different conditions (A and B) tested within-subject with a single binary choice trial per condition. In each of the two conditions, the binary choice is between old and new. My hypothesis is that participants will choose the new item more often than the old in condition A and the old item more often in condition B (as tested with a McNermar test). In addition, I would like to analyze reaction times. Here the hypothesis is that participants will be slower in choosing the new item than the old in condition A and vice versa in condition B. How do I test this hypothesis statistically? I.e., how do I test whether reaction times differ depending on the response a participant gives, and differentially so across two different conditions?

Comment: I think you can try a 2 factorial anova here with 1 wirthin subject factor condition (a, b) and one within subject factor item (new, old). There should be an interaction between the two factors.

Comment: But isn't it problematic that the factor item (new/old) is not independent of condition? - i.e., in a given condition participants will always either only have picked old OR new (because there is only a single trial per condition). That is, in some participants the factors are completely confounded (for those who picked old in one condition and new in the other) and in other participants only one item will be represented (for those who picked the same item in both conditions).

Comment: This would be a problem because we get "missing data" in some cases. How many items per condition did every participant rate? How many different items are there? How many participants are there? :)

Comment: There is a single trial per condition per subject. That is, we never have both data points (old and new) for one condition, but only one of the two in an individual subject.

Comment: I thought about checking whether the difference in RTs between predicted und unpredicted responses is significantly greater than zero with a one sample t-test (either averaged across both conditions A and B or in A and B separately). Would that be a valid approach? And if so, should I average the differences across both conditions or check for both conditions separately?